# How to assign a function that returns a list to another list in python?

Tags: python

I don't understand how do I assign this function to an identifier? Should I make it a list or something? I need to print the return values but I am unable to do so. Please help me out.

```
def mystery(l):
    if len(l)<2:
        return (1)
    else:
        return (mystery(l[1:])+[l[0]])

ll= [17,12,41,28,25]
new[:]=mystery(ll)
print(ll)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "Test2.py", line 8, in <module>
  new[:]=mystery(ll)   
  File "Test2.py", line 5, in mystery
    return (mystery(l[1:])+[l[0]])   
    File "Test2.py", line 5, in mystery
      return (mystery(l[1:])+[l[0]])   
      File "Test2.py", line 5, in mystery
        return (mystery(l[1:])+[l[0]]) 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: `return (1)` should be `return [1]`.

Comment: return (mystery(l[1:]+[l[0]]))? This might cause 'maximum recursion' error

Comment: I'll try these. Thank you.

Comment: It worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
def mystery(l):
    if len(l)<2:
        return [1] # change here
    else:
        return (mystery(l[1:])+[l[0]])

print(mystery(ll))
# output: [1, 28, 41, 12, 17]
```

Comment: Oh okay. I'll try that. Thank you!